# SAS substr merge

Tags: sas, match, substr

i think i know all of the parts on how to do this problem i have just had issues putting them together (outside of one small issue).

I have 2 data sets. one called "old_id" one called "new_id". The old "ID" is 7 characters (9 including hyphens... example : EX-123-45). The new ID format is 9 characters (11 including hypens... example : 88EX-123-45). there are some old_ids that were converted to new_ids but had an 88 or a 55 added in front of them. All other new ids have 22 in front of them and i need to avoid these because they have duplicate id's as the "old_id" but with 22 in front of them.

what i want to do with these is be able to match the info for the "old_ids" to the "new_ids" that are the new id's for the old id's (lol).

i know i can use

```
data ID_5;
set new_id;
ID5 = substr(right(id),2);
run;
```

this takes out the leading numbers and i could match on this. with the two files but then i have no way of getting the leading variables back (as far as i know). 
could i write an if statement to match IF the last 9 characters in "ID" in new_id match the old_id. IF the leading characters for ID in new_id = 88 or 55.

example of what the data i have looks like and what i want the end result

```
data for old_id.. this also contains 22 overrides (only about 20 though)

location ProductID    destination 
1        EX-123-45    724
1        EX-12A-B3    724      /* not all old ids have an override*/
5        EX-ABC-12    515
5        EX-ABC-14    953
7        22EX-ZYX-12  007
7        22EX-LMN-12  056
```

new_id file

```
location ID          destination
1        22EX-123-45  894
1        55EX-123-45  785
5        22EX-987-45  999
5        88EX-ABC-14  881
7        22EX-ZYX-12  678
7        22EX-LMN-12  254
```

what i want it to look like

```
location ProductID  destination 
1        22EX-123-45  894
1        55EX-123-45  724  /*old_id overrides destination*/
5        22EX-987-45  999
5        88EX-ABC-14  953  /*old_id overrides destination*/
7        22EX-ZYX-12  007  /*overwrites new_id destination*/
7        22EX-LMN-12  056  /*overwrites new_id destination*/
```

the majority of the 22's do not have overrides

Comment: Why do the first two have different DESTINATION values?  If the value from OLD overrides the value from NEW then shouldn't they both be 724?

Comment: in the what file? assuming you mean the "what i want" file it is because all id's that start with 22 could potentially have false matches based on the last 9 characters. They have their own overrides already written in in the old_id file which i do not have a problem match merging as they are already properly formatted,

Comment: Please provide details/examples of cases with how to override values of id that start with 22.

Comment: i have updated the files to contain their 22 counterparts which i should have done from the start. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

So if you can really tell which type of id is in the variable `ID` by the length of the value then use that to decide whether or not you need to remove two characters.

```
if length(id)=9 then old_id=id;
else old_id=substr(id,3);
```

If the hyphens are also not consistently inserted you might want to also remove them.

```
if length(compress(id,'-'))=7 then old_id=compress(id,'-');
else old_id=compress(substr(id,3),'-');
```

Comment: Tom, sorry for the delayed response its been a hectic day for me but i have updated my code for the question to better show what i want.  Sorry about the confusion before i had a meeting pop up and didnt get the time to review what i had wrote

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the original new_id can be solved by just creating a new variable to merge on.

```
data true_new new;
  set new_id;

  length match_id $9;

  if substr(id, 1,2) = '22' then call missing(match_id);
  else if substr(id,1,2) in ('88', '55') then match_id = substr(id,3);
  else match_id = id;

  if missing(match_id) then output true_new;
  else output new;

run;
```

I would now match the `new` with `old_id` based on the `match_id` field and then append `true_new` to the resulting dataset. These can be done in one step, but I find this a bit more cleaner.

Comment: I like this idea of making a file with only 88's and 55's and then removing those and merging. My other file also has overrides for the '22's but for the most part its overrides for the old_ids. So using this logic i would just merge with the override file twice. once as i have been doing without this updated logic (so it only does 22's) then once with the updated logic to override for the old_ids. although interesting note here the true_new file excludes the id and some of the destinations for the last 25 rows.

Answer (score 0):

First let's convert your listings into actual datasets we can code with.

```
data old_id ;
  input location ProductID :$11.  destination $ ;
cards;
1  EX-123-45  724
1  EX-12A-B3  724      /* not all old ids have an override*/
5  EX-ABC-12  515
5  EX-ABC-14  953
7  22EX-ZYX-12  007
7  22EX-LMN-12  056
;
data new_id;
  input location ID :$11. destination $ ;
cards;
1  22EX-123-45 894
1  55EX-123-45 785
5  22EX-987-45 999
5  88EX-ABC-14 881
7  22EX-ZYX-12  678
7  22EX-LMN-12  254
;
```

Now just join them and use COALESCE() function to pick the right value.  Your join criteria needs to handle the values that start with `22` differently.

```
proc sql ;
 create table want as
   select a.location
        , a.id as productid
        , coalesce(b.destination,a.destination) as destination
   from new_id a
   left join old_id b
   on (b.productid = substr(a.id,3) and a.id not eqt '22')
   or (b.productid = a.id and a.id  eqt '22')

   order by 1,2
 ;
quit;
```

Comment: I have them in datasets in sas as "old_id" and "new_id" already. i have rewrote your code to account for that but so far its been running for 10 minutes and it keeps going. the new_id file contains every location and every possible combination of location and destination so it is a pretty large file (a couple million rows)

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this more efficiently? i've let it run for awhile and it still doesnt execute. note: the execution of this query involves performing one or more Cartesian product joins that can not be optimized.